# Using Parallel.ForEach with ClientContext to download mulitple files

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have the following Parallel.Foreach loop to download multiple documents:

```
using (var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL))
            {
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web, a => a.Lists);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                int i = 0;
                SP.List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ArchivedData");
                SP.ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;
                int rowLimit = 100;
                var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                      <Query>
                                        <OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='ID'/></OrderBy>
                                      </Query>
                                      <ViewFields>
                                            <FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='ID' />
                                      </ViewFields>
                                      <RowLimit Page='TRUE'>" + rowLimit + "</RowLimit></View>";
                do
                {
                    SP.ListItemCollection listItems = null;
                    camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
                    listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                    ctx.Load(listItems);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    i += 100;
                    position = listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;    
Parallel.ForEach(listItems,
                        () => CreateClientContext(siteURL),
                        (currentfileItem, localContext) =>
                        {
                            ctx.Load(currentfileItem, x => x.File);
                            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                            var fileRef = currentfileItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
                            var fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileRef);
                            var fileName = @"c:\downloads\" + currentfileItem.File.Name;
                            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
                            {
                                fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                                //Generate MD5 HASH
                              ... 

                                    //Record HASH and File name in db with file name and title if there, and SharePointID
                             ...
                            //Remove the file we don't need it anymore
                            ...
                           }
                        });


items.AddRange(listItems.ToList());
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
                while (position != null);
```

Here is the CreateClientContext method I got from another article:

```
  private static ClientContext CreateClientContext(string url)
    {
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
        return context;
    }
```

I know I need this for the parallel foreach since it is not threadsafe.  But when I put in this code I get the following compiler error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions' because it is not a delegate type

So I am trying to find out which overload to use and I cannot seem to figure this out.  I know the error is stating that my lambda is being used in the place for ParallelOptions, but I can't figure out the error.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler seems to think you are using the wrong signature for your `Parallel.ForEach` call. Unfortunately, you do not give us the full call so I can't see which overload you are using.

A link for all overloads: [Parellel.ForEach official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2)

On another note, I'd tend to advise to run asynchronous query instead of your parallel call. It would spare some resources and if it is not your process that takes teams but the actual SP call, it would have the same performance.

[ClientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync Method - Official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/jj168848(v=office.14))

Comment: Edited for full call code

Comment: Your full call seems to rely on a potential overload `Parallel.ForEach(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TLocal>, Func<TSource,ParallelLoop>)` but I can't seem to find it. Please refer to the official documentation to try and get a potential overload. [Parallel.ForEach Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2)